# Get a type of Element of an array in Swift (through reflection)

Tags: swift, reflection, swift2

Let say I have following code

```
class Foo {
}

var fooArray : Array<Foo> = Array<Foo>()
// This is important because in my code I will get Any (vs Array<Foo)
var fooArrayAny : Any = foo
```

I want to be able to get a Type **Foo** out of variable fooArrayAny.

If I had fooArray, I would do something like that:

```
let type = fooArray.dynamicType.Element().dynamicType
```

However, this doesn't work with fooArrayAny. It says that it has no member Element()

Comment: fooArray.dynamicType.Element() is instantiating Foo, not returning a type. What type of object is in foo and what are you expecting to get out of it?

Comment: @ChrisGulley :I forgot to add dynamicType at the end to get it's type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set NSObject as the base class of Foo, then you could use the following code:

```
class EVReflectionTests: XCTestCase {    
    func testArrayInstance() {
        let fooArray : Array<Foo> = Array<Foo>()
        let fooArrayAny : Any = fooArray
        if let arr = fooArray as? Array {
            let i = arr.getArrayTypeInstance(arr)
            print("i = \(i)")
        }
    }
}

class Foo: NSObject {
}



extension Array {
    public func getArrayTypeInstance<T>(arr:Array<T>) -> T {
        return arr.getTypeInstance()
    }

    public func getTypeInstance<T>() -> T {
        let nsobjectype : NSObject.Type = T.self as! NSObject.Type
        let nsobject: NSObject = nsobjectype.init()
        return nsobject as! T
    }
}
```

This code is a snippet of my library  [EVReflection](https://github.com/evermeer/EVReflection)

**Update:**

I noticed a mistake in the code above. I used fooArray instead of fooArrayAny. When changing that to fooArrayAny I get the same error as you that the compiler does not have the Element. After playing around with this, I found out a solution that does work. Again it has parts of code of my [EVReflection](https://github.com/evermeer/EVReflection) library.

```
class EVReflectionTests: XCTestCase {    
    func testArrayInstance() {
        let fooArray : Array<Foo> = Array<Foo>()
        let fooArrayAny : Any = fooArray

        if let _ = fooArrayAny as? NSArray {
            var subtype: String = "\(Mirror(reflecting: fooArrayAny))"
            subtype = subtype.substringFromIndex((subtype.componentsSeparatedByString("<") [0] + "<").endIndex)
            subtype = subtype.substringToIndex(subtype.endIndex.predecessor())
            print("The type of the array elements = \(subtype)")
            if let instance = swiftClassFromString(subtype) {
                print("An instance of the array element = \(instance)")
                let type = instance.dynamicType
                print("An instance of the array element = \(type)")
            }
        }
    }

    // All code below is a copy from the EVReflection library.

    func swiftClassFromString(className: String) -> NSObject? {
        var result: NSObject? = nil
        if className == "NSObject" {
            return NSObject()
        }
        if let anyobjectype : AnyObject.Type = swiftClassTypeFromString(className) {
            if let nsobjectype : NSObject.Type = anyobjectype as? NSObject.Type {
                let nsobject: NSObject = nsobjectype.init()
                result = nsobject
            }
        }
        return result
    }

    func swiftClassTypeFromString(className: String) -> AnyClass! {
        if className.hasPrefix("_Tt") {
            return NSClassFromString(className)
        }
        var classStringName = className
        if className.rangeOfString(".", options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch) == nil {
            let appName = getCleanAppName()
            classStringName = "\(appName).\(className)"
        }
        return NSClassFromString(classStringName)
    }

    func getCleanAppName(forObject: NSObject? = nil)-> String {
        var bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
        if forObject != nil {
            bundle = NSBundle(forClass: forObject!.dynamicType)
        }

        var appName = bundle.infoDictionary?["CFBundleName"] as? String ?? ""
        if appName == "" {
            if bundle.bundleIdentifier == nil {
                bundle = NSBundle(forClass: EVReflection().dynamicType)
            }
        appName = (bundle.bundleIdentifier!).characters.split(isSeparator: {$0 == "."}).map({ String($0) }).last ?? ""
        }
        let cleanAppName = appName
            .stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "_", options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch, range: nil)
            .stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("-", withString: "_", options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch, range: nil)
        return cleanAppName
    }
}

class Foo: NSObject {
}
```

The output of this code will be:

```
The type of the array elements = Foo
An instance of the array element = <EVReflection_iOS_Tests.Foo: 0x7fd6c20173d0>
An instance of the array element = Foo
```

Comment: I noticed an error in the code. I added new code to the awnser.

Comment: I was trying to solve exactly the same problem JSON serialization/deserialization (because I wasn't happy with couple of libraries which I saw). I posted this question and literally in an hour found your library and happily throwed away all the code which I wrote

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5**

Its old but I want to share my version if someone needs it.

I use `ModelProtocol` and I suggests you use protocol so we can do operation to model via protocol (ex: static instantiating).

```
protocol ModelProtocol {}

class Foo: ModelProtocol {

}
```

Since I can't check type is Array, I use `CollectionProtocol` and create `Array` extension to get `Element` via protocol.

```
protocol CollectionProtocol {
    static func getElement() -> Any.Type
}
extension Array: CollectionProtocol {
    static func getElement() -> Any.Type {
        return Element.self
    }
}
```

Testing.

```
var fooArray: Array<Foo> = Array<Foo>()
var fooArrayAny: Any = fooArray

let arrayMirrorType = type(of: fooArrayAny)
String(describing: "arrayMirrorType: \(arrayMirrorType)")

if arrayMirrorType is CollectionProtocol.Type {
    let collectionType = arrayMirrorType as! CollectionProtocol.Type
    String(describing: "collectionType: \(collectionType)")

    let elementType = collectionType.getElement()
    String(describing: "elementType: \(elementType)")

    let modelType = elementType as! ModelProtocol.Type
    String(describing: "modelType: \(modelType)")

    // ... now you can do operation to modelType via ModelProtocol
}
```

Printing.

```
arrayMirrorType: Array<Foo>
collectionType: Array<Foo>
elementType: Foo
modelType: Foo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Foo {
    var foo: Int = 1
}
struct Boo {
    var boo: String = "alfa"
}

func f(array: Any) {
    let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: array)
    let arraytype = mirror.subjectType
    switch arraytype {
    case is Array<Foo>.Type:
        let fooArray = array as! Array<Foo>
        print(fooArray)
    case is Array<Boo>.Type:
        let booArray = array as! Array<Boo>
        print(booArray)
    default:
        print("array is not Array<Foo> nor Array<Boo>")
        break
    }
}
var fooArray : Array<Foo> = []
fooArray.append(Foo())
var anyArray : Any = fooArray   // cast as Any
f(anyArray)                     // [Foo]
var booArray : Array<Boo> = []
booArray.append(Boo())
anyArray = booArray             // cast as Any
f(anyArray)                     // [Boo(boo: "alfa")]
var intArray : Array<Int> = []
anyArray = intArray             // cast as Any
f(anyArray)                     // array is not Array<Foo> nor Array<Boo>
```

Comment: It will kind of work. However, I will have to extend switch case each time when I need to support new type. I was looking for some more generic apprach

Comment: generic approach? yoy still need to know how to perform with different types.